# why is my anchor tag extending 800 pixels?

Tags: html, css

website in question is work in progress [www.omegadesignla.com](http://omegadesignla.com)

Cant figure out why my anchor tag in the logo in the top bar is extending 800 px. I do not want the width of the logo to be clickable like that, how can i reduce the clickable area to the span of the logo itself? Help please, thanks.

```
    <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
       <ul class="title-area">
        <li class="name">

          <h1><a href="#"><img class="logo" src="img/omegalogogood.png"></a></h1>
        </li>
        <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon">
          <a href="#">Menu</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <section class="top-bar-section">

        <ul class="right">
          <li><a href="#pricing">About us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>

            <li class="has-dropdown">
              <a href="#">Services</a>
              <ul class="dropdown">
                <li><a href="#">Web Development</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Print Media</a></li>
                <!-- <li class="active"><a href="#">Active link in dropdown</a></li> -->
              </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
  .top-bar {
overflow: visible;
/*height: 3.75rem;*/
line-height: 2.813rem;
position: relative;
background: #333333;
margin-bottom: 0; 
}



.logo{
    width: 15%;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps add your current CSS/HTMl for this element to your answer?

Comment: question was edited please remove negative feedback it was a simple mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your anchor is expanding to 800px because it's in a block-level h1 element, which expands to fill all the space available. If you want it not to be 800px, you can set the width on the h1, rather than on .logo, and remove the width from .logo:

```
.top-bar h1 {
     width: 15%; /* or 20% or whatever */
}

.logo{
/*    width: 15%; */
}
```

The HTML structure you're using isn't semantically appropriate, though -- h1 elements are supposed to be for titles or top-level text. Why not put your logo in a div or a span?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize it was in an H1, I am still new to this so thanks a lot for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.top-bar .name h1 a {
   width: auto;
   height: 100%;
}
```

and

```
.logo {
  /* width: 20%; comment out width in logo class*/
  height: 100%;
}
```